# Retrieve crash report programmatically on macOS

Tags: c++, c, macos, qt, native

I am implementing my own C/C++ app using the Qt framework.
I want to retrieve the last crash log of my app at the time it crashes and send it to my API.
Is there a Apple native or terminal way to retrieve the log or do I have to retrieve it the hard way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The crash reports are in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports, you can read them from there. It's not a "hard way" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only if you publish your software via App Store. Crash reports are then gathered by the OS and can be retrieved on the App-Store-developer site. The user has the last say in whether the reports are delivered to Apple/you however.